# Teamcity - Conditional OctopusDeploy Create Release

Tags: sql-server, teamcity, devops, octopus-deploy

We have a SQL Server Visual Studio Database Project in Source Control. We have 10 databases in the solution. We build all database projects together, since there are dependencies/cross joins etc. Then depending on which file/project is changed, we want to conditionally deploy to 10 different Octopus projects.

1 Source Control ---> 1 Teamcity Build ---> 10 Octopus Deploy Projects

Eg: if it notices a file called eg ProductDatabase.sqlproj in %changedFiles.file%, then OctopusDeployCreate-Release to OctopusProduct

Eg if it notices a file called eg CustomerDatabase.sqlproj in %changedFiles.file%, then OctopusDeployCreate-Release to OctopusCustomer.

How would I create a conditional build step  for OctopusDeploy-CreateRelease in Teamcity using %changedFiles.file%?

[image].

[DevOps Stack](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4445/teamcity-conditional-octopusdeploy-create-release)

Answer (score 0):

Use **%PROJECT-NAME%** variable in Project field in Teamcity.

before **create release** step you have to set %PROJECT-NAME% variable using poewrshell script.

**How to set value of Teamcity Variable :** https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206808865-Setting-a-TeamCity-Configuration-or-System-parameter-from-a-PowerShell-Build-Step